# Rsync protocol name full path, not a module

Tags: rsync

Is it possible to name the full path to source directory in rsync command instead of the name of the module?

For example:

```
rsync -av rsync://10.171.73.23/home/user/work/tests .
```

instead of:

```
rsync -av rsync://10.171.73.23/ftp/work/tests .
```

(ftp is a module from /etc/rsyncd.conf)

When trying the first version I get `@ERROR: Unknown module 'home'`

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do that using the rsync protocol ; it relies on modules to define access rights. You could do it through SSH though :

```
rsync -av user@10.171.73.23:/home/user/work/tests .
```